# Python String Literals and Escape Sequence

Tags: python

I have a string

**'"No, thanks, Mom," I said, "I don't know how long it will take."'**

I assign it to a variable foobar

```
>>> foobar = """'"No, thanks, Mom," I said, "I don't know how long it will take."'"""
```

But when I print I get

```
>>> foobar
'\'"No, thanks, Mom," I said, "I don\'t know how long it will take."\''
>>>
```

How can I exactly print the same value of the string as I have assigned it?

Comment: what do you get when you `print foobar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print a string, use ... [`print`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print):

```
>>> foobar = """'"No, thanks, Mom," I said, "I don't know how long it will take."'"""
>>> print(foobar)
'"No, thanks, Mom," I said, "I don't know how long it will take."'
```

If you just enter `foobar`, Python prints the [*representation*](http://docs.python.org/library/repr.html) of foobar. The representation is designed to be valid Python code and/or useful for debugging, and is not meant to be outputted to users.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print foobar
```

`foobar`, by itself, calls `repr` on the string, which prints the string with escapes. `print foobar` calls `str` on the string instead.

Comment: This (needlessly) only works in Python 2.x. I see absolutely no reason why one should teach about the print *statement* at the cusp of 3.x and the much easier-to-grasp print *function*.

Comment: @phihag: Geez, sorry, man. I've been writing Python for so long that print-as-a-statement is second nature to me; I don't even think about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is printing the same value. It is only showing you the single quote escaped to differentiate it from the single quote used by the cmd line to display of the string.